# With which module can I create or blog content in Zikula 2.0.6?

Tags: zikula

because Zikula's official support forum was closed, which I found better, since in German, I have to look for help here.

I have Zikula 2.0.6 installed for the first time today and no module makes it easy to create content like the Wordpress blog.

Content Module generates 500 errors. News modules not compatible. Dizkus Module also displays 500 errors. Which module can I use to create content?

Thank you in Advance, Alexander

Comment: In the meanwhile News 1.2.0 has been released which works with Zikula 2.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be better to start with Zikula 1.5.6. E.g. News and Co tent are working fine with it but not with 2.0.6.

If English is to hard for you, you can also try in German. Some German developers and users are reading here as well.

Comment: Thank you for your tips and hints. Then I will probably start with Zikula 1.5.6. I have to delete Zikula 2.0.6 again. No, I thought that I can only post here in English, because here are only English developers. Is German language allowed here, too?

Answer (score 0):

You're totally right! The New News module was supposed to be released for Core-2.0 but the developer never did it. A Shame really.

Comment: Yes, a pity, but good, I know now and can fully start with Zikula 1.5.6. I would like to have Dizkus Forum with me, but I have to see if it will work in Zikula 1.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

There is still one important ticket open. See https://github.com/Portugao/News/issues/17. At last Camp Zikula we agreed to keep this function available.

There is a good reason not to release it yet.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for this Info, @rallek